# One Word : What do you call who chill / relax a lot?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, british-english, subcontinental-english

I need one word for people who chill / party / relax / play games / travel and just chill most of the time.

Some Word like '[Freizeit](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/freizeit)' , but it needs to be used as a noun for persons (eg, traveller, a gamer, a movie enthusiast, and not as travel, game). I hope I am clear.

Comment: Happy? Easy-going? Leisurely? Chillaholics? Lucky? This is a bit broad, and can use some helpful context. Do you want a positive, negative, or neutral word?

Comment: Also, is this the type of person who is doing these activities in their mother's basement or on a yacht in the Caribbean?

Comment: "Lazy" might work.  If the chillaxation is chemically induced, "stoner."

Comment: [Socialite](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/socialite), celeb, [social butterfly](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=social+butterfly), the unemployed (unlikely to travel much but definitely have free time on their hands), party-animal, teenagers, [gadabout](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gadabout?a=british) etc. etc. Are you looking for a negative or positive slant? Does the word have to be a noun or can it be an adjective? Why do you need this word, is it for a computer programme/game or a story? This sounds  like a nice question but it's very broad.

Comment: Layabouts.....?

Comment: Consider **hedonist**. *Hedonism  is ​living and ​behaving in ​ways that ​mean you get as much ​pleasure out of ​life as ​possible, ​according to the ​belief that the most ​important thing in ​life is to ​enjoy yourself*. When specifically enjoying luxury, voluptuous pleasures and gastronomic delights, you may use the term "sybarite".

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the word you are looking for is **playboy**, though in later years it has taken on a connotation of sexual promiscuity.

"[The Original Playboys](http://www.getkempt.com/article/the-12-original-playboys-of-the-jetset-60s) relied upon a perfect storm of pleasurable circumstances: The world was at peace; airplanes began flying internationally; their parents were members of the 1920’s cafe society and raised progressive, well-mannered, fashion-forward children; they possessed unparalleled wealth, there was no Internet – as a result, they will forever remain an inimitable breed of elite, professional pleasure seekers, the likes of which the world will never see again."

They definitely chill a lot, party a lot, and travel a lot.

Comment: Playboy is male-gender. Something that can be used for both genders ?

Answer (score 0):

Tourist

"Travel exotic" tipped your hand here.  There are many types of people who exhibit your other behaviors: Trust fund kid, hippy, retired, but if you're doing this while traveling you're a tourist.